# Inject ArrayList using RequiredArgsConstructor

Tags: dependency-injection, javabeans, lombok

I tried to inject List into constructor through lombok RequiredArgsConstructor

```
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor (onConstructor = @_(@Inject))
    public class ClassA {

        @NonNull private List<GoodSkill> skills;
        ......
     }
```

However then have errors:

> [tomcat:launchProperties] 
>           org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'ClassA' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/XXXXX/ClassA.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type java.util.List<\GoodSkill>: expected at least 1
>   bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

It seems there is NO bean of for "List<\GoodSkill>"? I guess there's some special rule when injecting List or other Collections? And as for GoodSkill class, I guess I also should add annotation like @Component?

========

edit:
More weird thing is, I re-build package and now it's no longer complaining find no bean for List<\GoodSkill>, but no bean for GoodSkill. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting is possible only for managed beans. So, for a list you should have somewhere something like:

```
@Component
public class GoodSkillList extends ArrayList<GoodSkill>{}
```

for container to find.

Perhaps you have? If you have many of such beans container/Spring might not be able to decide which to use. In that case you can delimit the possible alternatives many ways for example you could set `ClassA` to accept only:

```
@NonNull private GoodSkillList skills;
```

or alternatively you can research howto inject/autowire by name.